# Redireccionar salida de comandos bash a archivos

Tags: ubuntu, bash, shell

necesito guardar todos los logs de salidad de mis comandos bash en un archivo de texto.
Cuando hago lo siguiente me da error

```sh
alejandro@alejandro-X556UAK:~$ sudo touch salida.txt
[sudo] password for alejandro: 
alejandro@alejandro-X556UAK:~$ sudo du -h ./* > salida.txt
bash: salida.txt: Permission denied
alejandro@alejandro-X556UAK:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Es porque el dueño del archivo es root, pero cuando hace `sudo du` los permiso para el archivo son como el usario.  Puede `chown alejandro salida.txt` o arranca con `sudo -i`.

Answer (score 2):

Al crear un fichero con sudo, efectivamente, le otorgas la propiedad a root:

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ sudo touch prueba.txt
[sudo] password for alfonso: 
alfonso@foresthost:~$ ls -l prueba.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 ene 15 23:36 prueba.txt
```

No veo la necesidad de hacerlo así, al menos para volcar la salida del comando du, que está en el paht de cualquier usuario por defecto:

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ which du
/usr/bin/du
alfonso@foresthost:~$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Como ha apuntado @Duston, puedes cambiar el propietario al fichero con chown:

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ sudo chown alfonso:users prueba.txt 
alfonso@foresthost:~$ ls -l prueba.txt 
-rw-r--r-- 1 alfonso users 0 ene 15 23:36 prueba.txt
```

Y, en todo caso, si quisieses que el fichero siguiese perteneciendo al superusuario, siempre puedes darle permisos de escritura a "otros":

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ sudo chmod 646 prueba.txt 
alfonso@foresthost:~$ ls -l prueba.txt 
-rw-r--rw- 1 root root 0 ene 15 23:36 prueba.txt
```

De manera que usuarios no pertenecientes al grupo root puedan editar el archivo:

```
alfonso@foresthost:~$ sudo du -h ./* > prueba.txt && echo "Parece que funciona"
```

Mediante el operador && conseguimos que el comando echo sólo se ejecute si la ejecución del comando previo, du, resulta exitosa. 
Suerte.